# Change language in keycloak login page

Tags: java, html, authentication, keycloak, locale

I'd like to include a button that allows me to change the language. I checked the Keycloak documentation, and it should be possible to add it from the "theme" section Keycloak Theme [Theme keycloak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FS3Nn.png). However, it didn't appear for me [my realm theme keycloak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6Vce.png). Could someone share a solution with me for this issue?

I attempted to access the settings from the theme screen.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Keycloak, you need to go to the 'Localization' tab.